# Azure VM Nic With Loopback Address and No Connectivity

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

we have a vm which is in Azure but we're not able to connect to it. I checked the serial log under boot diagnostic and it has the following error:

> ======== Microsoft Azure VM Health Report - Start 2020-02-19T20:50:47.2786733Z ========
>   {"reportTime":"2020-02-19T20:47:44.9492172Z","networkAdapters":[{"name":"Loopback
>   Pseudo-Interface
>   1","status":"Up","macAddress":"","ipProperties":[{"protocolVersion":4,"address":"127.0.0.1","isDhcpEnabled":false},{"protocolVersion":6,"address":"::1","isDhcpEnabled":false}]}],"remoteAccess":null,"accounts":{"windows":{"adminAccountPasswordExpired":false,"adminAccountDisabled":false}},"services":[{"errorControl":"Normal","exitCode":0,"name":"TermService","processId":2708,"serviceType":"Share
>   Process","startMode":"Auto","startName":"NT
>   Authority\NetworkService","state":"Running","status":"OK"}

The key part I think is the `"name":"Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1"`It has no mac address as above and uses IP of 127.0.0.1, Has anyone come across this before and know how to get the NIC to be recognised. I've changed the NIC and changed IP, but cannot seem to resolve this.

Comment: why do you think thats key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, 127.0.0.1 is assigned to a loopback interface. It represents the localhost address. The captured health report is meanless and not enough to identify why you are not able to connect to that Azure VM.

First, you can verify if the VM status is running on the overview of the virtual machine portal. Then check if there is any port blocking in the NSG on the **networking** of VM, then try to RDP or SSH to that Azure VM. You can get more details on **diagnose and solve problems** under overview.

If you still could not connect to it. Try to **resize** or **redeploy** your Azure VM. If you have important data, please backup your OS and data disk before you redeploy it. You also could get more details on [how to use boot diagnostics to troubleshoot virtual machines in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/boot-diagnostics).

Hope this could help you.

Comment: After many hours of investogation and with Microsoft looking at this, it was concluded the driver failed to load therefore no NIC was detected. The loopback-psuedo-1 nic was a red herring, as mentioned above. After creating a nested vm we could see no NIC was being attached and the OS is corrupted. Thanks for all your help.